# iOS 8 UITextView Fixed text alignment

Tags: ios, localization, ios8, uitextview, text-alignment

I have a UITextView in my View Controller, I've overridden the class and in **awakeFromNib** method I did

```
    if (([NSLocale characterDirectionForLanguage:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]] == NSLocaleLanguageDirectionRightToLeft)) {
//Arabic
    }
else {
//English
}
```

For Arabic I did `[self setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];` also tried

```
[self setBaseWritingDirection:UITextWritingDirectionLeftToRight forRange:[self textRangeFromPosition:[self beginningOfDocument] toPosition:[self endOfDocument]]];
```

also tried

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.text];
    [string addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                   value:paragraphStyle
                   range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];

    self.attributedText = string;
```

by following multiple SO Questions, but no success at all :( My TextView is always right aligned when device language is Arabic. I want it left aligned because I want to show English text.
[image: Red UITextview - Fixed Alignment issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was setting the property in **awakeFromNib** method and that was the issue. I set the textAlignment in my view controller class and it worked fine for me. If anybody can shed some light on this behavior please do.